# Finding zero-one vectors in the row space of a matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose that $M$ is a square matrix with all elements on its main diagonal equal to $1$, and every row containing exactly two off-diagonal elements equal to $-1$; all other elements are equal to $0$. The kernel of $M$ is nonzero and, indeed, contains a vector with all its coordinates nonzero. Does it follow that the row space of $M$ contains a (nonzero) zero-one vector?

In case it matters, the sum of all elements in every column of $M$ is nonpositive, and $M_{ij}M_{ji}=0$ whenever $i\ne j$.

Comment: Given a vector space, is it decidable whether it contains a nonzero zero-one vector?

Comment: @VilleSalo If the vector space is given as a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ by some basis vectors, you can just iterate over all $2^n-1$ non-zero 0-1-vectors an check whether one is in there.

Comment: Heh, good point. Is it in P?

Comment: Is the condition of nonempty kernel essential?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: If the kernel is trivial, then *everything* is in the row space of the matrix. I am not sure as to how important is to have the kernel not trapped in a coordinate hyperplane.

Comment: So, it is inessential. Btw, it may be the case that the existence of a nonzero 01-vector holds even for the lattice spanned by the rows.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: 1) Well, we cannot say that the condition "the kernel contains a nowhere-zero vector" is inessential. 2) Absolutely, I am also trying to think in this direction.

Comment: Why don't you just ask a *very well known open question* the way it has been initially posed (in a finite set of numbers each number is a sum of some other two; does it follow that there is a subset with sum $0$?)

Comment: @fedja, do you have a name/reference for the problem when posed the way you have stated it?

Comment: @kodlu: https://mathoverflow.net/q/16857/9924

Comment: @fedja: Because it is not equivalent. My question concerns with a *stronger* statement, with the goal is to evaluate a certain direction in solving the "very well known open question".

Comment: You just mean that the numbers can repeat in your formulation? I heard the question with the same assumption (repeated entries allowed), but OK.

Comment: @fedja: No, this is mostly not about repetitions. If we identify our set with a vector $a$, and $M$ is the associated matrix, then the original problem is to prove that $a^\perp$ contains a nonzero vector $\varepsilon\in\{0,1\}^n$. This is, in general, not equivalent to "the row space of $M$ contains a nonzero vector $\varepsilon\in\{0,1\}^n$".

Comment: But with all quantifiers: "*For every* $a$ in the kernel of $M$, $a^\perp$ contains a 0-1 vector" it is, isn't it?

Comment: @fedja: Ok, but this is already not the original question. Anyway, the source of the discrepancy is that the kernel of $M$ can contain vectors other than $a$.

Comment: "but this is already not the original question": I perceive the original question as "for every $a$ in the kernel of every such $M$", but OK, this discussion is not very interesting; we'd better just try to solve it :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is true:

> For any square matrix $M$ with all elements on its main diagonal equal to 1, and every row containing exactly two off-diagonal elements equal to −1 (with all other elements are equal to 0), the row space of $M$ contains a nonzero zero-one vector. Moreover, there is a linear combination of the rows with the coefficients $0$ and $-1$ only which yields such a vector.

This is in fact the main lemma of [this preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02586); see, on the other hand, [this MO problem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380683/9924) for the explanations.